# Mute Left/Right Audio Effect using Superpowered sdk

Tags: android, c++, audio, superpowered

I have integrated superpowered [CrossExample](https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-Audio-iOS-Audio-Engine/tree/master/Android/CrossExample) successfully and now i need to apply mute right/left audio effect, and i have checked

```
SuperpoweredMixer.h , SuperpoweredSimple.h
```

these files but unable to find relevant methods to apply this effect,

so are there any other methods to do this thing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just simply zero every even or odd sample, with some simple ramp when it turns on or off to prevent 'clicks'.

Superpowered doesn't really offer a function for such tiny task. You can do it with the SuperpoweredStereoMixer, but it may be too complex for this simple job.

Here is code snippet

```
bool Tempo::process(short int *output, unsigned int numberOfSamples) {
    bool silence = !playerA->process(stereoBuffer, false, numberOfSamples, volA);
    echo->process(stereoBuffer, stereoBuffer, numberOfSamples);
    reverb->process(stereoBuffer, stereoBuffer, numberOfSamples);

    float *mixerInputs[4] = {stereoBuffer, NULL, NULL, NULL};

    float *mixerOutputs[2] = {stereoBuffer, NULL};

    float mixerInputLevels[8] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};

    float mixerOutputLevels[2] = {left, right};

    mixer->process(mixerInputs, mixerOutputs, mixerInputLevels, mixerOutputLevels, NULL, NULL,
                   numberOfSamples);

    if (!silence) {
        SuperpoweredFloatToShortInt(mixerOutputs[0], output, numberOfSamples);
    }
    return !silence;
}
```

Comment: i have tried as you mention in answer but i am not getting exactly as you can see in my edited question. btw thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, now i am able to implement the effect perfectly using your approach.